# Variables inside a template are not evaluated

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have Jade markup looking like this:

```
li(ng-repeat="parcel in parcels | filter : filterActiveAreaParcels")
  .parcel-image(style="background-image:url({{parcel.image}});")
```

For some reason sometimes I get 404 error while it tries to retrieve `http://localhost:3501/%7B%7Bparcel.image%7D%7D`, It doesn't happen all the time, but sometimes. Though all images are being retrieved and shown on the page properly.
What can be the problem here?

Comment: `style="background-image:url({{parcel.image}});` is not closed.

Comment: @iMom0, just a misspelling here, fixed, thanks. In source code it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

`http://localhost:3501/%7B%7Bparcel.image%7D%7D` is `http://localhost:3501/{{parcel.image}}`

Remember, the HTML is actually in the DOM when angular compiles it. So your browser is (for a brief moment, before the app bootstraps), having something like this in the DOM:

```
<div class="parcel-image" style="background-image:url({{parcel.image}})">...</div>
```

And when it see the style property, it's hitting your server with `/{{parcel.image}}`.

That's why you're getting the occasional 404 there.

EDIT: You can use [the ngStyle directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angStyle) to get around this:

The `ngStyle` directive will watch an object and apply the styles it contains.

So in your html:

```
<div class="parcel-image" ng-style="styles">...</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
app.controller('ParcelImageController', function($scope) {
  $scope.parcel = {/*some object*/};
  $scope.style = {
    'background-image': 'url(' + $scope.parcel.image + ')'
  };
});
```

[Here a fiddle with an example of this in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/8qYME/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now, how can I workaround this issue in the most compact quick way? I suppose, I put {{parcel.image}} value in to another attribute, like data-image="{{parcel-image}}", then how to better add the style attribute with the respective value when angular loads all its internal stuff and scope?

Comment: See my answer again - I added a solution.